# Stuck at GRUB menu on boot Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, 22.04

Picture of the GRUB output after looking into partition `(hd2,gpt5)`:

[image]

So as you can see in the picture, I'm stuck in GRUB. I know where the Ubuntu system is, it's in `(hd2,gpt5)`, and the root `/` file is there, but when I try to boot it doesn't work. I've tried loading the kernel too but I can't figure out what to set `root` to. As in `root = /dev/sd??`

Comment: You don't need to set root = /dev/sda, instead you can use set root=(hd2,gpt5). If you are able to boot into Ubuntu. Try boot repair tool.

Comment: Arjun K Shibu I tried this but now I get the error no init found

Comment: Can you post an image?